# Error compiling interface implementation

Tags: java, generics

I get an error for: `a.getLargest(a.create());`
in the main method. It says that

> I have to implement the method in `Geo`

```
public abstract class Measurable<T> {    
   abstract double getMeasure();
   public static <T extends Measurable<T>> T getLargest(ArrayList<T> objects){
       T largest = objects.get(0);
       for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i ++){
           if(largest.getMeasure() == objects.get(i).getMeasure()){
               largest = objects.get(i);
           }
       }
       return largest;     
   }
}
```

And in a separate file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;    
public class Test extends Measurable {      
    private Geo test;
    private static ArrayList<Geo> object;       
    public Test(){
        test = new Geo();
        object = new ArrayList<Geo>();
    }

    public double getMeasure() {
        double size = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            size = object.get(i).getArea()*object.get(i).getPerimeter();
        }
        return size;
    }           

    public ArrayList<Geo> create(){
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                test = new Geo(i, i);
                object.add(test);
            }
            return object;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Test a = new Test();
            a.getLargest(a.create());

        }
  }
```

And thats the GeoClass

```
public class GeometricObject extends Measurable<GeometricObject>{
```

Comment: Java8 allows default method body for interfaces, what's your java version?

Comment: I use the Java 8 Version

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't understand what is meant by "implementing" an interface. Your `Test` class implements `Measurable` in a non-generic way. So actually you are implementing `Measurable<Object>`. So far so good, but then you created a `Geo` object. In your question, you did not show that `Geo` implements `Measurable<Geo>`, so I assume it is not. If `Geo` did not implement `Measurable<Geo>`, then the call to `getLargest` would fail because `getLargest` calls `getMeasure` which most likely does not exist in `Geo`. Instead, you should implement `Measurable<Geo>` in `Geo` class.

```
public class Geo implements Measurable<Geo> {
    public double getMeasure () {
        //some code
    }
    //other code
}
```

I guess your confusion here is might be that you think when `Test` implements an interface, all its members implement it. **But that is not true**, ok?

And another thing to remember is that **when you don't specify a generic type argument, it defaults to `Object` not the type implementing the interface!**

Comment: @Prog111 Please edit your question to let me see your new code

Comment: ok I changed the code above. I had changed Measurable to an abstract class and the other classes extend Measurable.

Comment: Now I get an error because of that: T largest = objects.get(0); that is a nullPointerExc.